# Blog posts to separate pages?

Tags: expressionengine

How can I have blogs on my expression engine site post directly to a new page with a url? Right now my blogs are static and taking up entire pages (up to 10 blogs on a page) Is there a way to automate this so that every blog that is posted automatically is set up on it's own page with a unique url?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  EE has good documentation and this is pretty well covered.  I think you also get something like this pre-built for you in the default install.

In a nutshell tho what you probably want is an entry template.

So let's say you have a template now called "blog" and the template called "index" that you are now using for your multiple blog listing.

In your "blog" template group you want to create a new template called say, "entry". Then you want to build a link from each entry in the index to the individual entry page.  The path would be something like /blog/entry/{url_title}.

There's more to it than that but that but that should be enough to get you started.  If you have more questions you can ask another question and show us what you have tried.